# PHP mysql_fetch_assoc() error

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data that is collected in a function, that contains my query. I am returning the data back to the main page and printing it using a while loop however i am getting this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
```

Comment: Avoid using the mysql library in PHP, use the mysqli library instead. Did you check the reference manual on php.net for this function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Solution is simple: stop using `mysql_*` API ;)

Answer (score 7):

try to return your result like

```
return $query;
```

cause you are returning string(your `mysql_result($query, 0)` returning 0th position column value only), need a query result for `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

try the corrected function:
function get5star(){
    `$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM`5starproducts`";
    $query = mysql_query($strSQL);
     return $query;
  }`